# Change Twig url() output in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, decorator, router, symfony5

What is the file/class that ultimately executes the Twig `url()` function, like here: `<a href="{{ url('app_home') }}">Home</a>` in twig.

I know I can use a decorator to change functions with something like:

```yaml
App\Services\MyRouter:
    decorates: 'router'
    arguments: ['@App\Services\MyRouter.inner']
```

and

```php
public function generate($name, $parameters = [], $referenceType = self::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
{
    $name = 'test'.$name;

    return $this->router->generate($name, $parameters, $referenceType);
}
```

The above changes the route which affects other areas like loading controllers.

All I'm after is the final output in the twig document. I haven't been able to find the the correct service to decorate.

**edit**

Based off the answers I have been working with twig.extension.routing but now I just get an "Unknown "path" function." exception. My expectation would be for nothing to happen and my function returns the original method.

```
App\Service\TwigUrlDecorator:
    decorates: 'twig.extension.routing'
    arguments: ['@App\Service\TwigUrlDecorator.inner']
    public: false

<?php
// src/Service/TwigUrlDecorator.php

namespace App\Service;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;

class TwigUrlDecorator extends AbstractExtension
{

    public function getPath($name, $parameters = array(), $relative = false)
    {
        return parent::getPath($name, $parameters, $relative);
    }

}
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? You want to change the generation of routes, but only for the Twig part? Only for some routes? Only in very specific cases?

Comment: I mentioned that all I want to change is the actual output of `{{ url() }}`, I'm not after how to make the changes, just the the file I need to decorate.

Comment: Why not use another Twig function then? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: My other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66949490/1246494 ) might help. I just need to modify the output of the url() function.

Comment: To that new error:  you forgot to inject the decorated service into your extension. Why not inject `UrlGeneratorInterface`  instead?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried adding `__construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $generator)` and changing my method back to `return $this->generator->generate(...)` with the same result.

Comment: What is "the same result"? Please open a new question or edit the current one to contain all relevant information

Comment: Sorry I meant to say same exception, so no change in outcome. I have edited my question with my changes. But I've made a new question now I've learnt a bit more about services, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016566/how-to-use-symfony-decorator-pattern-to-change-a-twig-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url` twig function is executed by `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension::getUrl()`.

You can find the class definition [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php), and the specific method [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/8bc0a8f78479de316bf898e21f8d591e97fd72d4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php#L51). The service is defined [here](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bundle/blob/82527ecf6f37e1c28dc73a6ee5385c99e216334f/Resources/config/twig.php#L113), where you can see the service name is `twig.extension.routing`.

I guess you could decorate the extension, but considering how simple it is, it might be simpler just to [define your own URL generating twig function by defining a new Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html).

Comment: Your resources look like what I'm after to answer my question. Creating my own twig function was my first thought, until I discovered decorating. Do you have any good references for twig functions?

Comment: You can use that one as an example. Documentation is [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html).

Comment: I'll look into that. But thinking about it, decorating the function might be a better solution for front end designers, they can keep using the standards they know.

Comment: Whatever approach you find better. The answer should help you either way.

Comment: I've been working with `twig.extension.routing` but I must be doing something wrong. I've updated my answer also.